# React Toast notify on authenticated function

Tags: reactjs, function, authentication, toast

How can I get this toast notification to show when authentication is passed in the following code? Ive tried what is commented here but not valid code.

```
   import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

    class Home extends React.Component {

//https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify#demo

//notify = () => toast("Wow so easy !");

    render() {
        return (

            AccountService.authenticated() ? (
                <Sites.component history={this.props.history}/>
                // {this.notify}
            ) : (
                    <div className="col-12 mt-3 ml-3">
                        <h3 className="h4 text-left mb-4 green-text">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon size="lg" icon={['fas', 'lock']} />
                            Please login to continue</h3>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/login" >
                            <Button color="primary" type="submit" value="submit">
                                <LocalizedMessage of="login" />
                            </Button>
                        </Nav.Link>
                    </div>
                )
        )
    }
}

export default {
    component: Home
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we use redux, I ended up using this method: [enter link description here](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify#usage-with-redux)

and configuring the options globally in App.js
[enter link description here](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify#what-if-i-told-you-that-the-toastcontainer-is-optional)